# Docs state that x==y does not imply x!=y, is this true?

Tags: python, boolean-logic

As question states, python docs state a rather contradictory line. The line in question can be found on [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

The line in question states, rather bluntly:

> "There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The truth of x==y does not imply that x!=y is false."

Is there a statement in Python that fulfills this claim? Or is it only limited to convoluted gotcha code.

Comment: Keep reading: "Accordingly, when defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the operators will behave as expected." This statement is in reference to defining `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` in classes. You should always define both.

Comment: It means that you can define your own type that fulfills the claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example where both == and != are True is the following

```
  class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True

  b1 = MyClass()
  b2 = MyClass()
  print b1 == b2
  print b1 != b2
```

both lines above will print True

Comment: For some reason I was unaware you could overload operators in Python. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @MatthewMuller: The section of the documentation you quoted is precisely about overloading operators.

Comment: @BrenBarn: This is one of those times I was blindly reading documentation. Strange things happen.